# Getting KeyError after reading in pipe-separated CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I read in a pipe-separated CSV like this

```
test = pd.read_csv("http://kejser.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Country.csv")
test.head()
```

This returns

```
  SK_Country|"Number"|"Alpha2Code"|"Alpha3Code"|"CountryName"|"TopLevelDomain"
0                    1|20|"ad"|"and"|"Andorra"|".ad"                          
1                 2|4|"af"|"afg"|"Afghanistan"|".af"                          
2        3|28|"ag"|"atg"|"Antigua and Barbuda"|".ag"                          
3                  4|660|"ai"|"aia"|"Anguilla"|".ai"                          
4                     5|8|"al"|"alb"|"Albania"|".al"
```

When I try and extract specific data from it, like below:

```
 df = test[["Alpha3Code"]]
```

I get the following error:

> KeyError: ['Alpha3Code'] not in index

I don't understand what goes wrong - I can see the value is in the CSV when I print the head, likewise when I open the CSV, everything looks fine.

I've tried to google around and read some posts regarding the issue here on the stack and tried different approaches, but nothing seems to fix this annoying problem.

Comment: You probably need to specify a delimiter when you read in.

Comment: Hey Chris, thank you for a fast answer, but can you specify your answer, i am brand new to Python, so I don't know exactly what you mean?

Comment: Miradulo's answer explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how everything is crammed into one string column? That's because you didn't specify the delimiter separating columns to `pd.read_csv`, which in this case has to be `'|'`.

```
test = pd.read_csv("http://kejser.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Country.csv", 
                   sep='|')
test.head()

#    SK_Country  Number Alpha2Code Alpha3Code          CountryName  \
# 0           1      20         ad        and              Andorra   
# 1           2       4         af        afg          Afghanistan   
# 2           3      28         ag        atg  Antigua and Barbuda   
# 3           4     660         ai        aia             Anguilla   
# 4           5       8         al        alb              Albania   
# 
#   TopLevelDomain  
# 0            .ad  
# 1            .af  
# 2            .ag  
# 3            .ai  
# 4            .al
```

Comment: Thank you miradulo, that made sense, I had no idea i need to do that, but it makes perfect sense that i need to split it up.
I'll mark your reply as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment by @chrisz, you have to specify the delimiter:

```
test = pd.read_csv("http://kejser.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Country.csv",delimiter='|')
test.head()
SK_Country  Number Alpha2Code Alpha3Code          CountryName  \
0           1      20         ad        and              Andorra   
1           2       4         af        afg          Afghanistan   
2           3      28         ag        atg  Antigua and Barbuda   
3           4     660         ai        aia             Anguilla   
4           5       8         al        alb              Albania   

  TopLevelDomain  
0            .ad  
1            .af  
2            .ag  
3            .ai  
4            .al
```